# Implementing AntisymmetricRNN in Keras

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement the AntisymmetricRNN described in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09689.

Working in Keras, I guess I have to implement my own layer so I have read https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/. Instead of starting from a plain layer as explained there, I reckon the best would probably be to extend one of the existing RNN, but [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L237) has

- RNN
- SimpleRNNCell
- SimpleRNN

The documentation isn't verbose enough for someone my level about what these classes do/are, and consequently I am having a hard time figuring out what should be my starting point.

Any help, both in terms of where to start and what to actually look out for, and all sorts of suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should implement your own `Cell` (don't need to change `RNN`). You are going to use an `RNN(yourCell, ...)`. Although this hint is not really a great help (you will need to dive into code), the suggestion is to get a paper showing the LSTM formulas and see what the LSTM cell is doing.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you for the suggestion. I do understand most of the code for the cell, but what baffles me is that its first argument is units. As far as I understand, units are the "neurons" in the layer, and so I would expect that parameter to be defined at layer level, not cell (which should be, indeed, a single neuron). To add to that, one usually writes something like LSTM(100, … ) and that 100 is the number of neurons in the layer - while the docs say that a RNN layer should take cells as argument. These asymmetries make it hard to figure out the logic.

Comment: Nono, a cell is not a neuron. A cell is the "module" that you attach to an `RNN` layer that contains the "recurrent mathematical operation".

Comment: An `LSTM(...)` layer is nothing different from an `RNN(cell=LSTMCell(...), ...)` layer.

Comment: @DanielMöller I understand now, thank you. A bit of "language barrier" in logic between me and whoever coded Keras. I truly despise Python and its libraries at large, but at least with your helpful comments and directions I have now been able to make my code work. If you would like to post your comments as an aswer, I will mark it as the accepted solution. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Keras, all recurrent layers are `RNN` layers with a certain `Cell`.

The definition is `RNN(cell=someCell)`

So, the `LSTM` layer follows the same principle, an `LSTM(units=...)` layer is equal to an `RNN(cell=LSTMCell(units=...), ...)` layer.

That said, to implement your recurrent layer (if it doesn't break the recurrent flow step by step or jump steps), you need to implement your own cell. You can study what is happening in the [LSTMCell](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1790) code, compare it with the papers and adjust the weights and formulas to your need.

So you will have your own `RNN(cell=yourCell)`.